# Audio streaming with get request, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, amazon-s3, streaming

I have a few mp3 files on an Amazon S3 file and I can access them through Cloudfront. I know that I could use the cloudfront url as source on an audio html tag and would be enough to reproduce the music in a website BUT I was wondering if it is possible to create a middleware to get the audio data from cloudfront and then, from the frontend client, use a get request to retrieve the data and then pass that data to an audio tag to reproduce it. I don't want to use the url because I don't want it to be public.

Is it possible? How? Thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

Comment: I have read your question but not sure what output you want

Comment: @DataCure one of the problems is that I don't know what kind of output I can get to transform it to something an audio tag can read